# How to see all keys for a PrivateTempStore?

Tags: 8

The Drupal class `PrivateTempStore` allows for setting and getting key-value pairs within a temporary data store. The class includes the `$storage` property which then has a `getAll()` method for retrieving all items in the store. However, this is protected, and so cannot be used by an instantiated `PrivateTempStore` object.

Is it possible, given a `PrivateTempStore` object, to retrieve a list of all keys currently used in the store?

Comment: The replacement for `$_SESSION` is the session object in the request, which has a method [all()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21Session%21SessionInterface.php/function/SessionInterface%3A%3Aall/9.1.x). See https://www.drupal.org/node/2380327

Comment: @4k4 Thanks – that's very useful to know, I had no idea. As is so often the case with Drupal, there are many options…

Comment: OK, in this case it is not only an option, it is the official replacement.

Comment: Understood – I meant that this is one option, `PrivateTempStore` is another, and there are doubtless more…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, with the current `PrivateTempStore` you don't have access to the list of keys. You're welcome to create your own `TempStore` class if you want different functionality, but I don't see why that is needed here.

The whole point of `PrivateTempStore` is to stash temporary data for a user, under a given key. If you don't know the key, then you have no knowledge of the type or structure of the data stored there, so in general you won't know how to use it. If your intention is to store a collection of data of a known type (stored in an associative array, for example) so that you can iterate over it later, then store the array itself under a known key, don't store each array element separately. Then you can retrieve the array later from the known key and do a foreach over each element of the array.

Comment: Hah, you're completely right of course – I had somehow totally forgotten that each key-value pair doesn't need to simply be a single string/integer/whatever. Using an array as the value will do what I need very nicely. I asked about this as I may convert some code that uses `$_SESSION` setting/getting to use a more Drupal-friendly approach. And somehow I had tunnel vision about the possibilities with both approaches! Thanks for your answer.